# Android app not running anymore after performing Expo Eject "error: package does not exist" and "error: cannot find symbol"

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-unimodules

**CONTEXT**

This is the first React Native app I have made and we started with Expo not knowing which functionalities we were going to use. Turns out we had to do some platform-specific configuration, so we had to eject Expo. Ever since we have not been able to get Android running and thus also not been able to do builds for Google Play.

I have scoured the internet for solutions and feel like I've tried everything but can not get it to work. I am a rookie at this as I have only used React Native with the Expo Managed workflow and feel lost now.

**ENVIRONMENT**

Node 16.15.0
Npm 8.5.5
React 17.0.2
React Native 0.68.2
Expo SDK 45.0.0
Android Studio:
SDK 33
SDK Tools 33

**PROBLEM**

When running `npx react-native run-android` I get tons of errors that either say `error: package android.xxx.yyy not found` or `error: cannot find symbol`
I am in no case experienced with Android configuration and I assume I did some damage during the ejection of Expo but I have not been able to find a solution anywhere online. If anyone knows any solution I am happy to try it, please let me know if I should provide more information!

**FULL OUTPUT**

As StackOverflow won't let me post the full error, I've uploaded it on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/cJ2HJDpw

Here are two examples but there's plenty more:

```
/Users/shendric/Desktop/Palau/PalauApp/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/apploader/AppLoaderProvider.java:4: error: package android.content.pm does not exist
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
```

```
/Users/shendric/Desktop/Palau/PalauApp/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/core/interfaces/Package.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
  default List<? extends InternalModule> createInternalModules(Context context) {
                                                               ^
  symbol:   class Context
  location: interface Package
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming across this issue, in the end I had to re-eject expo for android only and reapply the config I had done previously... This was the only way to get it to work again, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Use expo r in the terminal or expo start because npx react-native run-android
is for using React Native CLI.

Comment: Hi Ahma, we don't want to use expo anymore and we are using React Native CLI...

Comment: Well, if you don't wanna use expo anymore then you would have to create a whole new project using "npx react-native init AwesomeProject" and then type "npm run android" to run the app in android simulator and you won't have any issues. however if you faced any problem setting up android environment check react native main guideline here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup